# Android custom IcsSpinner (from ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner, android-theme

Currently I'm using IcsSpinner since I want a dropdown spinner across all devices.
This is what I want to achieve (showing closed spinner and expanded):

[image]

however I'm not able to do so. I have tried this code:

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
     android:id="@+id/myspinner"
     style="@style/SpinnerStyle"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
     android:minHeight="@dimen/spinner_min_height"
     android:prompt="@string/pick_one" />
```

with the style:

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/white_text</item>
</style>
```

and drawable **spinner_selector.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/spinner_grey_bg"/>
</selector>
```

however the output is something like this:

[image]

I attempted another way by customizing the views in the adapter by doing this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                        R.layout.spinner_entry_textview, adapterArray);
mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

with **spinner_entry.textview.xml**:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tv_spinner_entry"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="@dimen/min_height_touch"
android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
android:textColor="@drawable/spinner_text_selector"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
/>
```

and the **spinner_text_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white_text" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white_text"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white_text"/>
<item android:color="@color/red_text"/>
</selector>
```

but im getting this output wich is almost what I want but it also paints gray and red text when closed. (the first element where the arrow points should be dark gray background with white text)[image]

also tried applying styles to default listview since the spinner seems to have an internal listView but didn't do anything:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/spinner_text_selector</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/spinner_text_selector</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/white_text</item>
</style>
```

*Any ideas on how to achieve this? It would be much appreciated.*